# SQL Query returns Nulls for entire table that is populated

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am a total noob at MySQL and databases in general, but I am trying to get better at it by creating some fictitious DBs.
I am attempting to use a JOIN query to pull data from 4 different, completely populated tables. Using:

```
SELECT orders.OrderID,orders.customerID,orders.orderdate,orders.notes, Customer.*, orderitem.qty, donut.*
FROM Customer INNER JOIN OrderItem
Left Join orders ON customer.customerID = orders.orderID
AND orders.orderID = orderitem.OrderID
Left JOIN donut ON orderitem.donutID = donut.donutID
WHERE orders.customerID = 002  or customer.customerID = 001  ;
```

using this, I get all NULLS from my "orders" table which has 4 columns. Each of these columns has data in them.

I know (I think) its an issue with "FROM Customer INNER JOIN OrderItem
Left Join orders ON customer.customerID = orders.orderID" because if switch it to Right joins, it populates the "orders" table information, and makes all other other tables return NULLS. I am just at a complete loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unlikely `join` condition:

```
 ON customer.customerID = orders.orderID
```

You probably mean:

```
 ON customer.customerID = orders.CustomerID
```

Because you are looking at order information, I would suggest inner joins:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.customerID, o.orderdate, o.notes, c.*, oi.qty, d.*
FROM Customer c INNER JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.customerID = o.customerID INNER JOIN
     OrderItem oi
     ON o.orderID = oi.OrderID LEFT JOIN
     donut d
     ON oi.donutID = d.donutID
WHERE c.customerID IN ('001', '002');
```

I'm not sure how donuts fit in, so that is still a `left join`.  I put the customer ids in single quotes.  If there are leading zeros, then they are probably strings.

Comment: Holy crap. That completely fixed it, your first suggestion. I could have sworn I tried that. Thank you. I did try your 2nd suggestion of code, and it returns back an empty set. But thank you again!

Comment: @Talenus the error in your original join condition is also in the 2nd suggestion, here, so I suspect `ON c.customerID = o.orderID` was intended to be `ON c.customerID = o.customerID`.